# Adding Authentication to existing Yesod project with Haskell

Tags: haskell, authentication, authorization, yesod, templating

I have been using [this guide](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/authentication-and-authorization) in order to add authentication and authorisation to my project. I am new to Yesod and have been running into some problems:

I am using the following foundation data:

`data App = App (TChan Text)`

For my authentication i need this data type:

`data App = App SqlBackend`

How can i combine the two? Do i then also have to change existing functions?

In the end i run everything like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = runNoLoggingT $ withSqliteConn "email.db3" $ \conn -> liftIO $ do
    runSqlConn (runMigration migrateAll) conn
    chan <- newTChanIO
    warp 3000 $ App chan
-- Backend SqlBackend needs to be initilized with conn (see below)


{- OLD
main = do
    chan <- newTChanIO
    warp 3000 $ App chan
-}

{- NEW
main = runNoLoggingT $ withSqliteConn "email.db3" $ \conn -> liftIO $ do
    runSqlConn (runMigration migrateAll) conn
    warp 3000 $ App conn
-}
```

I know that i have to combine the two. I read [this article](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/initializing-foundation-data). How do i get `chan` and also `conn` together? It might sound trivial, but there is little documentation out there.

Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically people make their `App` datatype a record with multiple fields. For example, the [scaffolded Yesod project](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-scaffold/blob/281e8a067b30da6b66d0a642213f2ad5fe6c6239/Foundation.hs#L19-L25) uses this code:

```
data App = App
    { appSettings    :: AppSettings
    , appStatic      :: Static -- ^ Settings for static file serving.
    , appConnPool    :: ConnectionPool -- ^ Database connection pool.
    , appHttpManager :: Manager
    , appLogger      :: Logger
    }
```

The [example code](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/initializing-foundation-data#initializing-foundation-data_conclusion) you linked to does that as well:

```
data App = App
    { homepageContent :: Html
    , visitorCount    :: IORef Int
    }
```

So what about something like this:

```
-- Small caveat: this is code untested
data App = App
        { backend :: SqlBackend
        , chan    :: TChan Text
        }

main :: IO ()
main = do
    chan <- newTChanIO
    runNoLoggingT $ withSqliteConn "email.db3" $ \conn -> liftIO $ do
        runSqlConn (runMigration migrateAll) conn
        warp 3000 $ App { backend=conn, chan=chan}
```

You would have to change old code accessing your `TChan`, but once your App is a record, you can add more fields without making changes to the rest of your codebase.

As a side note, have you considered using the [Yesod scaffolding](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/scaffolding-and-the-site-template)? You'd start off with all this handled for you, with a bunch of other niceties and best practices already implemented for you.